# Often used directories

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have about 3 or 4 directories I go to often on my machine and would love a way to easily go straight to these directories instead of always typing them.

The best way I could think of to do this is set environment variables.  However doing "cd env:" doesn't work.

Anyway have any ideas on the best way to do this?

****Edit 1****
I'm hoping for a approach that I don't lose once my session is close(for example, closing PS window.).

Comment: My answer applies to all PowerShell sessions, because it's defined in the PowerShell profile script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a `HashTable` in your [PowerShell profile](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613488%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) script that points to the various folders. Then, simply reference them using the short-hand:

```
$FL = @{
    Dir1 = 'c:\windows\system32'
    Dir2 = 'c:\program files\Common Files'
    Dir3 = 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys'
}

cd $FL.Dir1;
cd $FL.Dir2;
cd $FL.Dir3;
```

Alternatively, you could develop small functions, and place them into your PowerShell profile script.

```
function sys32 {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param ()
    Set-Location -Path 'c:\windows\system32';
}

function mkeys {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param ()
    Set-Location -Path 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys';
}

function cf {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param ()
    Set-Location -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files';
}

# Call the functions
sys32;
mkeys;
cf;
```

Comment: The problem I have with this approach is once you close PS you lose the HT.  I was hoping for something I can do once and not have to worry about each session.

Comment: @Michael: If you put this in your PowerShell profile script, you don't have to worry about re-defining it every time. That is why I linked to the PowerShell profile documentation.

Comment: I missed that.  I check it out and try it.

Comment: It worked perfect after using the profile!  I used the HT approach.

Comment: @Michael: Glad to hear it mate!

Answer (score 5):

You can create a PS drive for each one in your profile:

```
New-PSDrive Dir1 -PSProvider FileSystem -Root 'c:\windows\system32'
New-PSDrive Dir2 -PSProvider FileSystem -Root 'c:\program files\Common Files'
New-PSDrive Dir3 -PSProvider FileSystem -Root 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys'
```

Then just CD or SL to the drive name:

```
cd dir1:
sl dir2:
```

Answer (score 4):

Create a small function in your [profile](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847857.aspx) for each.

```
function gohome {
    set-location c:\users\username
}
```

Comment: The problem I have with this approach is once you close PS you lose the HT. I was hoping for something I can do once and not have to worry about each session.

Comment: @Michael As alroc said, put it in your profile. You'll never have to worry about it again.

Comment: This worked good too but I decided to use the HT approach.  I did give you a  up vote though.

Answer (score 2):

Get your profile using notepad $profile from within powershell.

Put one of the above functions in there and restart powershell.

Comment: `Function Pro {notepad.exe $profile}`, just type `pro` and go.

Answer (score 1):

Some readers may prefer the machine wide profile over the per user `$profile`.  If so, edit or create a file in this location.

```
%windir%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1
```

IIRC, it runs before the user profile is loaded, whether that is advantage / disadvantage you decide.